# Entity Framework outputs XML instead of JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, entity-framework, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

In my controller classes I have a lot of methods which output properly formatted JSON data. All of them perform a database query.
E.g.

```
// GET api/User
public IEnumerable<Object> GetUsers()
{
    var query = from user in db.Users
                orderby user.Name
                select new { Name = user.Name};

    return query.AsEnumerable<Object>();
}
```

Now I'd like to return the properties of one of my classes.

```
public IEnumerable<Object> GetProperties()
{
    return typeof(MyClass)
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
}
```

However, instead of outputing JSON Entity Framework gives me some XML like

```
<ArrayOfstring xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <string>Property1</string>
    <string>Property2</string>
</ArrayOfstring>
```

I've tried to convert the output in the controller method.

```
public string GetProperties()
{
    var results = typeof(ComplexInfo)
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results, Formatting.Indented,
        new JsonSerializerSettings {
            PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
        });
}
```

Unfortunately it's still outputting XML.

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">[
  "Property1",
  "Property2",
]</string>
```

How can I make sure to retrieve JSON objects from the controller?

Comment: are you using web-api?

Comment: Can you show your code for the actual request. Also do you always want to return json?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had also faced same issue in my web api. solution is, you have to remove XmlFormatter from WebApiConfig.

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
 {
  public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
  {
     config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

       var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.
      FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType ==      "application/xml");
    config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
 }
}
```